# Countdown timer with a for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm making a pomodoro timer to help get better at Javascript. So far i've managed turn the user's input into minutes, but I cannot seem to create a countdown timer using the console.log.

**WARNING: It seems to break the browser**.

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/YcBh9/

Javascript:

```
        var doc = document,
            timer = doc.getElementsByClassName('timer')[0],
            button = doc.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

        button.onclick = function () {
            var input = doc.getElementById('input').value;
            var speed = (input * 1000) * 60;

            for (i = speed; speed > 1; i - 1000) {

                console.log(i);
            }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="timer"></div>I am going to spend
<input id="input"></input>minutes working
<button>Go!</button>
```

Comment: You would probably do well by using setTimeout/setInterval instead of a loop

Answer (score 1):

your for loop isnt deincrementing properly, causing a infinite loop.
you need `-=` not just `-`, and you are checking `speed` when you should be checking `i`,

```
for (i = speed; i > 1; i -= 1000) {
```

Comment: Are you sure? `input` will get coerced into `Number` when it is used in the expression `(input * 1000) * 60)`.

Answer (score 1):

First, your loop is incorrect. The stop condition is `speed > 1`, but you're never modifying `speed`. Also, `speed - 1000`, will not do anything. You need either `speed = speed - 1000` or `speed -= 1000` to modify `speed`. I imagine what you really wanted is something like:

```
for(i = speed; i > 1; i -= 1000) {
    ...
}
```

However, it is better to use `setInterval` in this case. You don't want to use loops because JavaScript is single-threaded and the loop will lock up the UI (as you have discovered). So you can do something like this:

```
button.onclick = function () {
    var input = parseInt(doc.getElementById('input').value, 10);
    var speed = (input * 1000) * 60;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        speed -= 1000;
        console.log(speed);

        if(speed <= 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            console.log("All done!");
        }
    }, 1000); //poll every second.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `for` loop, use `setTimeout` instead. Otherwise, the loop will block any further code and user interaction, including any attempt to update the UI to show the timer's progress. Try this instead:

```
button.onclick = function () {
    var input = doc.getElementById('input').value;
    var remaining = (input * 1000) * 60;

    function updateTimer() {
        console.log((remaining/1000) + " seconds remaining");
        remaining -= 1000;
        if(remaining > 0) setTimeout(updateTimer, 1000);
    }
    updateTimer();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YcBh9/1/